# Erlang cowboy matching multiple routes

Tags: http, server, erlang, cowboy

I want to match requests as /friend_request/something ; /friend_request/somethingElse in the same module. I have the following code

```erlang
defmodule Server do

  def start() do
    dispatch_config = build_dispatch_config()
    { :ok, _ } = :cowboy.start_clear(:my_http_listener,
      [{:port, 8080}],
      %{ env: %{dispatch: dispatch_config}}
    )
  end

  def build_dispatch_config do
    :cowboy_router.compile([
      { :_,
        [
          {"/register", Elixir.Register, []},
          {"/login", Elixir.Login, []},
          {"/friend_request/:page", Elixir.Friend_Request, []},
          {"/send_message", Elixir.Send_Message, []},
          {"/home", Elixir.Home, []}
        ]}
    ])
  end

end
```

The problem is that all requests like /friend_requests/something doesn't go to my Friend_Request module, even thought the [documentation](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.8/guide/routing/?fbclid=IwAR3UmgukQQSwN4Z2kvb0W9PQ13xowaKPDiHlPVdRK6pcs7ugLtDwqs6mkJg) says otherwise. For all requests I get 404 not found http request.

How can I send such requests to the same module ?

EDIT: By documentation it should be *page and not :page. For some reason it worked with :page for a while and then it stopped now it is working fine with *page.

Comment: Is your Friend_Request module have init/2 method? What http request you send to cowboy?